# Update Row Id=1 FROM Row Id=2

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a Product table include id and name. Let say I have,

```
Id Name
1  A
2  B
3  C
```

I want to update row where Id=2 with the value of row where Id = 1. This is what I am looking,

```
Id Name
1  A
2  A
3  C
```

I am trying different syntax but nothing working.

Update: The above example uses one column but I have many columns to update.

Comment: you only want to do this for Id=2 or other rows as well ?

Comment: I only need to update row x from y

Comment: @user960567 is y=x+1 always or it can change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like that:

```
UPDATE P1 SET P1.Name = P2.Name, P1.X = P2.X, ......
FROM Products P1 CROSS JOIN Products P2 WHERE P1.Id = 2 AND P2.Id = 1;
```

Comment: @user960567 - Then, why don't you give us all the details ? Why are you keeping it a secret ?

Comment: The number of the columns that you need to update is not relevant, just separate them with commas like that: `t1.name=... , t1.address=... , t1.company=...`

Answer (score 1):

You need update every column

```
UPDATE Product
SET
    Product.Name = anotherRow.Name
    , Product.AnotherColumn = anotherRow.AnotherColumn,
    --, Other columns
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        Name
        , AnotherColumn
        --, other columns
    FROM Product
    WHERE ID = 1
    ) anotherRow
WHERE
    Product.ID = 2
```

Or if after data was copied, you will delete row where ID = 1, then update only ID column

Comment: Check the below answer.

Comment: Both queries do same job